# Add event to other user's Outlook calendar

Tags: vba, outlook

Our email system is being updated to Exchange 365.  I have a database that was adding calendar events (employee time off) to a public folder.

Well, the updated Exchange does not use public folders.  So, we created a user and shared the calendar, and now I'm trying to figure out the code to add/change/delete the event to/from another user's calendar through Access 2016 (and 2012 hopefully).

The code below is me just trying to figure out how to add so has no error checking.  In fact, I created a database just for this.

I did figure out how to add it to my own calendar, but it will not work adding it to the new Exchange 365 user calendar.  Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Command15_Click()
    
    Dim outMail     As Outlook.AppointmentItem
    Dim objNS       As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim objFolder   As Outlook.MAPIFolder        'get name of other persons folder
    Dim objRecip    As Outlook.Recipient        'other persons name
    Dim strName     As String        'the name or email of the persons folder
    Dim objAppt     As Outlook.AppointmentItem
    Dim objApp      As Outlook.Application

    On Error Resume Next
    ' name of person whose Calendar you want to use - right
    strName = "janet 2"
    Set objNS = objApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set objRecip = objNS.CreateRecipient(strName)
    Set objFolder = objNS.GetSharedDefaultFolder(objRecip, olFolderCalendar)
    'Set outMail = Outlook.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)
    Set outMail = objFolder.Items.Add
    outMail.Subject = "test"
    outMail.Location = ""
    outMail.MeetingStatus = olMeeting
    outMail.Start = Me.BegDate
    outMail.End = Me.BegTime
    outMail.RequiredAttendees = strName
    outMail.Body = "test message"
    outMail.Save
    'Set outMail = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` hides errors. Makes debugging impossible. Leads to a poor a question as there can be no information regarding results.

Comment: So what happens when you step through your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whole code that works:

```
    Dim outMail As Outlook.AppointmentItem ' meeting or one-time appointment in Calendar folder
    Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace ' accessing data sources owned by other users
    Dim objFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder 'get name of other persons folder
    Dim objRecip As Outlook.Recipient ' Other persons name
    Dim strName As String ' the name or email of the persons folder
    Dim objAppt As Outlook.AppointmentItem
    Dim objApp As Outlook.Application

    'name of person whose calendar you want to use
    strName = "ICT Time Off"

    Set objApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")    'Bind to existing instance of Outlook
    Set objNS = objApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    Set objRecip = objNS.CreateRecipient(strName)
                                        
    Set objFolder = objNS.GetSharedDefaultFolder(objRecip, olFolderCalendar)
    'Set outMail = Outlook.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)
    Set outMail = objFolder.Items.Add
        
    outMail.Subject = "test"
    outMail.Location = ""
    outMail.MeetingStatus = olMeeting
    outMail.Start = Me.BegDate
    outMail.End = Me.EndDate

    outMail.RequiredAttendees = strName
    outMail.Body = "test message"
        
    outMail.Save
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work (sort of).  I changed back Set OutMail to what I originally had:

```
Set OutMail = Outlook.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)
```

And I changed Outmail.Save to Outmail.Send.

It now puts it in the other user's calendar, but as unaccepted. I need it to go in as Accepted. I'm going to research this now.

Comment: Changed Set OutMail = objFolder.Items.Add and Outmail.Send back to Outmail.Save, and now it save automatically to other User's calendar.  Yay!